# German word for plastic pry tool

Tags: single-word-request

What is the German word for the plastic pry tool used to open laptops and smartphones?  (see image below)

[image]

Comment: Do you know what it is called in English (or any other language in fact)?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Taterhead already used the english name. It is "pry tool" (sometimes also "prying tool" or "plastic pry tool").

Comment: In the watch making trade, where similar tools have been used for centuries to open watch cases, theses are simply called "Gehäuseöffner oder "Gehäusemesser" (für Druckböden/Stülpgehäuse).

Comment: Another English word for them is "Spudger" if that's any help.  Mine are made from stainless steel or various strength plastics.

Answer (score 6):

This is a *Gehäuseöffner*.

The word *PVC-Gehäuseöffner*, as suggested by others, is not appropriate:

1. The word *PVC-Gehäuseöffner* <s>implies</s> might imply that it was an opener of PVC cases and covers (*Öffner für PVC-Gehäuse*) and not an opener made of PVC used to open cases and covers (*aus PVC bestehender Öffner für Gehäuse*).
2. We cannot infer from the picture that the tool is made of polyvinyl chloride. It could be made of any other plastic material.

Comment: Regarding your first point: An opener of PVC cases would have to be spelt *PVC-Gehäuse-Öffner.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du hast Recht (vgl. § 44 (1) des amtlichen Regelwerks).

Answer (score 5):

A similar question was asked here: 
http://www.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-790182-Pry-tool.html

The word seems to be PVC-Gehäuseöffner.

Comment: Actually *PVC-Geheuseöffner* would be appropriate if the pry tool is made of PVC.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found some at Conrad today.  It seems the name is **Öffnungswerkzeug**.

[image]

Comment: Aside from the fact that _Smartphone Öffnungswerkzeuge 7tlg._ is orthographically wrong, _Öffnungswerkzeug_ is a generic term for all tools used to open something. It includes _Gehäuseöffner_, but it also includes _Dosenöffner_ (can openers) or _Flaschenöffner_ (bottle openers). For this reason, the term is not appropriate. Otherwise one could simply call it a _Werkzeug_ (tool) or, more anstractly, a _Ding_ (thing).